# One die probability questions

Tags: probability, prime-numbers, dice

I was given this exercise:

If a standard die has twice the probability of rolling an odd number than an even number.
Find the probability of rolling a non-prime number with this die.

My attempt:

P(even) = 1/3

P(odd) = 2/3

P(non-prime) = P(1)+P(4)+P(6)

```
         = (1/6)(2/3) + (1/6)(1/3) + (1/6)(1/3)

         = (4/18) = (2/9)
```

Comment: Do you know which prime numbers are possible outcomes?

Comment: There's not enough information to answer the question. Perhaps you meant to imply that all odd numbers have the same probability of being rolled and all even numbers have the same probability of being rolled? (Also for completeness you should specify how many sides the die has.)

Comment: I was unsure of how to write my question, I'm sorry, I have updated with my attempt. Also the question I gave was copy and pasted from my exercise sheet so that is all the information I am given on this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I interpret your problem statement to say that you have a standard (6-sided) die, but it's non-standard in that the probability of rolling an odd number is twice the probability of rolling an even number.

$P($non-prime$)=P($rolling a 1, 4, or 6$)$

$P($rolling $1)=P($odd$)\cdot P($that odd number is 1$)=(2/3)(1/3)=2/9$

$P($rolling $4)=P($even$)\cdot P($that even number is 4$)=(1/3)(1/3)=1/9$

$P($rolling $6)=P($even$)\cdot P($that even number is 6$)=(1/3)(1/3)=1/9$

Thus, $P($non-prime$)=(2/9)+(1/9)+(1/9)=4/9$.

Comment: You're assuming that all odd numbers are equiprobable and all even numbers are equiprobable. That's given neither in the question, nor in your interpretation of it in the first sentence.

Comment: @jonki I interpret a standard die to have equal probability for the faces to occur, based on the symmetries of the die. Without this assumption, how would you proceed to address the question?

Comment: Certainly that's the case for a standard die. But this is a non-standard die. If it's more probable to roll an odd number than to roll an even number, who knows what the probabilities for the individual faces are. As I wrote in a comment under the question, I wouldn't proceed to answer it -- there's not enough information given to answer it. If I were to make additional assumptions in order to answer it anyway, I'd explicate those.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming by a standard dice you mean one that has six sides and contains the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6.

If P(even) = 1/3 and P(odd) = 2/3 then to find the chance of rolling a non-prime we must find the chance of rolling a non-prime that is even or odd then adding the probability.

First let us consider the amount of even non-primes from 1-6. There is only two even non-primes and those are 4 and 6.

Because 4 and 6 are two of three possible numbers and there is a 2/3 chance you randomly select these numbers from the three possible choices those numbers. Then you multiply that with the probability of rolling an even number.

```
(2/3)*(1/3) = (2/9)
```

Then let us consider the probability of rolling a non-prime odd number. In the number 1-6 there is only one non-prime odd number out of the three number 1-6. So the chance of randomly choosing a non-prime odd number out of the three choices is 1/3. Then multiply that with the chance of rolling a odd number.

```
(1/3)*(2/3)=(2/9)
```

The answer is the sum of rolling both an non-prime odd and a non-prime even.

```
(2/9)+(2/9)=(4/9)
```

Thus P(non-prime) = (4/9)

Comment: You're assuming that all odd numbers are equiprobable and all even numbers are equiprobable. That wasn't given in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If we interprete the question to require that: The probability of *any particular* odd number is twice that of *any particular* even number, but its an *otherwise* standard die, so odd numbered results are equiprobable, and even numbered results also.

There is $3$ of each kind, and a $2:1$ weight ratio of odd:even, but equally weighted within the kinds.

Meaning that: $\Bbb P(X=x)=\begin{cases} (1/3)(2/3) & :x\in \{1,3,5\}\\ (1/3)(1/3) & :x\in\{2,4,6\} \\ 0 & : \text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$

Now you can find: $\Bbb P(X\in\{1,4,6\})=4/9$